# Upgrading OpenSSH, new version not "active"

Tags: linux, ssh, upgrade

I need to upgrade openSSH to version >8.1 on a custom linux distro (looks like RHL derivative).

I downloaded the sources and built a rpm locally (Ubuntu 20).

On the custom linux distro I perform:

```
root@custom [ ~ ]# rpm -ivf /root/pack/openssh-8p4.cl.x86_64.rpm 
Verifying packages...
Preparing packages...
openssh-8p4.cl.x86_64
```

However, when I check for the version, I see the old version:

```
 root@custom [ ~ ]# ssh -V
 OpenSSH_7.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2v-fips  5 May 2020
```

Reboot of the system or sshd does not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the contents of that RPM package?

Comment: the rpm built from the source published on official site, mostly .c & .h files

Comment: What is in the RPM?

Comment: the source of openssh 8.4, I cannot understand your question

Comment: You can't run source code! Didn't you build binary RPMs?

Comment: yes, you're right. the rpm is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some issue in your rpm binary file and due to this you are getting this issue please share the source code info and how you created that rpm file.

For more reference: How to create a rpm file check the below article.

[Build RPM Package](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/02/rpm-build-package-example/)